# How to make proper calculation in mysql tabe data using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table named `transactions` structured like this

```
id      dr_balance    cr_balance  initial_balance
1        0.00          10000.00       10000.00
2        0.00           5000.00
3       2000.00            0.00
```

I want to show like this one

```
id      dr_balance    cr_balance  initial_balance
1        0.00          10000.00       10000.00
2        0.00           5000.00       15000.00
3       2000.00            0.00      13000.00
```

My modal

```
    function make_calculation()
{
    $query = $this->db->select_sum('cr', 'dr');
    $query = $this->db->get('accounts_transactions');
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result[0]->make_calculation;
}
```

my controllers

```
public function new_deposit()
{
    $this->load->model('Accounts_transaction_model');
    $data['calculation'] = $this->Accounts_transaction_model->make_calculation();
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('transaction/new_deposit', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

My view

```
               <?php
                   foreach ($calculation as $key ):
               ?>

             <?php  
                 $cr = $key['cr'];
                 $dr = $key['cr'];
                 $initial = $cr - $dr;
             ?>
             <input type="text" value="<?php echo $initial; ?>" name="initial" />
             <?php  endforeach; ?>
```

Errors are given bellow:-

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$make_calculation

Filename: models/Accounts_transaction_model.php

Line Number: 51

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: transaction/new_deposit.php

Line Number: 16

Backtrace:
```

I want to make SUM of `cr_balance` then minus of `dr_balance` and insert the result on `initial_balance`. This calculation will be updated for each new row. I need some help about that.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have tried? What are you struggling with?

Comment: Sir, I have shared my Controller, Model and View codes.